# Función del condicional simple en "¿qué necesidad habría de llamarme?"

Tags: condicional

Ejemplo:

> A ver, si no necesitara mi ayuda, **¿qué necesidad habría de llamarme?**

En primer lugar estoy tratando de entender si es realmente una oración condicional. ¿De verdad se debe considerar la frase *¿qué necesidad habría de llamarme?* como la apódosis para la prótasis *si no necesitara mi ayuda*? Veo que formalmente la frase tiene la conjunción condicional *si* y la estructura la prótasis + la apódosis. Pero la acción expresada en la apódosis no es irreal, ¿verdad? Pensaba que tal vez la apódosis estuviera omitida... Tal vez haya que considerar la parte interrogativa por separado?

Comparo la oración en questión con

> Si trabajaras bien, tendrías clientes.

(pretérito imperfecto de subjuntivo + condicional simple; la acción de la prótasis es irreal),

y veo que la acción de la prótasis de la oración en questión es real (él/ella sí llamó a otra persona).

Otra pregunta sería: determinar la función del condicional simple en la frase en questión. Estaba descartando versiones incorrectas: pues no es „una acción futura considerada desde un momento del pasado“, entonces no „pega“. Tampoco es „una hipótesis irreal“. Entonces queda „una suposición“ (pero ahora después de haber leído la respuesta de aparente001 lo entiendo mejor).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60571/discussion-on-question-by-aurora-funcion-del-condicional-simple-en-que-necesid). Moví los comentarios pues son obsoletos (la pregunta tenía votos negativos) pero puede que haya gente que aún quiera consultarlos.

Answer (score 1):

> Si no necesitara mi ayuda, ¿qué necesidad habría de llamarme?

Otra forma de expresar esto:

> ¿Por qué me habrá llamado?  O: ¿Por qué me habrá querido llamar?

La persona que pone la pregunta está especulando.  Está tratando de usar lógica para razonar, por qúe Fulano haría tal cosa, por qúe me llamaría, por qué me tendría que llamar.

Answer (score 1):

> A ver, si no necesitara mi ayuda, ¿qué necesidad **habría** de llamarme?

Lo primero que debes preguntarte es quién ha de llamarte. Si se trata de la misma persona que necesita tu ayuda, entonces lo correcto sería:

> A ver, si no necesitara mi ayuda, ¿qué necesidad **tendría** de llamarme?

Siendo él/ella sujeto omitido.